# How to grep a log file content within a particular timestamp range in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a log file, which has data in the following format

```
[1361991081] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;qa-hadoop1;CPU Load;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL - load average: 18.29, 18.14, 18.10
[1361991371] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;CRITICAL-SERVICES_FOR_LAST_24_HOURS;qa-hadoop1:Critical Services;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CPU Load,Memory,
[1361994681] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;qa-hadoop1;CPU Load;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL - load average: 18.02, 18.06, 18.11
[1361994971] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;CRITICAL-SERVICES_FOR_LAST_24_HOURS;qa-hadoop1:Critical Services;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CPU Load,Memory,
```

I contains all the data for the past 7 days.I want to grep this file to show the logs for yesterday. Here date is showing as timestamp. I am using the following command

```
cat /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log |grep qa-hadoop1|grep CRITICAL|grep NOTIFICATION | awk -F, '{ if ($1>"[1361989800]" && $1<"[1362076199]") print }'
```

where `1361989800` is the calculated timestamp value for `Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 IST 2013`

and  `1362076199` is the calculated timestamp value for `Thu Feb 28 23:59:59 IST 2013`.

This works well but the problem is how do i pass `1361989800` and `1362076199` as arguments??

Answer (score 2):

You only need `awk` for this.

```
awk -va=1361989800 -vb=1362076199 '{gsub(/[][]/,"")}/qa-hadoop1|CRITICAL|NOTIFICATION/&&$1>a&&$1<b' file
```

The `-v` options allows you to pass in variables. Also by using `gsub` to remove the brackets for integer comparison on the first fields *(space separated not comma that is)*.

---

**Notes:**

`grep` reads files so you don't need to `cat file | grep 'pattern'` just `grep 'pattern' file` also you can use alternation like `egrep 'qa-hadoop1|CRITICAL|NOTIFICATION' file` so you don't need to pipe to `grep` three times.

A more `awkish` version of `awk -F, '{ if ($1>"[1361989800]" && $1<"[1362076199]") print }'` is `awk -F, '$1>"[1361989800]" && $1<"[1362076199]"'` you don't need the `if` construct and the default block in `awk` is print.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using command line parameter assignment:

```
grep qa-hadoop1 input | grep CRITICAL| grep NOTIFICATION | \
  awk -F, -v b=1361989800 -v e=1362076199 \
    '{ if ( $1 > "["b"]" && $1<"["e"]") print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

apart from your `cat|grep|grep|grep|awk`, I would ask, why you set comma `,` as `FS` of awk, and later compare $1 with timestamp? $1 is from beginning till the first comma, which is not correct.

The `FS` should be space, if you want to compare date like in your `if` statements.

it may work if you remove `-F,` from your awk line part. try it.

simpler, you could take `[` or `]` as `FS`.